# Script to Copy cells to another sheet, for example, based on the Background Color of the Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

First of all I'm completly new to Google Sheets and Scripts so I'm trying to learn all by myself, so sorry if I'm asking something 'stupid'

So my problem is: I've created a Script to basically add a Background color to a cell, based in a certain condition. What I wanted to do now was identify all cells with that added Background color, select the entire row in which they are contained and copy all the information to another sheet.

I was trying to do it with an if condition, but I have no idea how to select the entire row or if the condition I'm using to get the Background color is right. Can anybody help me? Thank you so much!

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var r = s.getRange('F:F');
  var v = r.getBackgrounds();
  for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    if(v =='B7E1CD')
      s.getCurrentCell.copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange(20,1)); //don't mind this instruction, I know it isn't right
```

Comment: define `spreadsheet`. Is it a sheet of the same spreadsheet file or of a different spreadsheet file?

Comment: Try using v[i][0]==‘#B7E1CD’ And also you need you need to use the filter method if you’re going to use that kind of a range definition as an alternative you could use the range definition that uses get last row method

Comment: Keep in mind when you use get values or get backgrounds that you always get a two dimensional ray return to you even if it’s only a single column or a single row. I realize that’s not intuitive but it’s a reality

Comment: Hi @Mario ! It's a sheet in the same spreadsheet file. Sorry if it wasn't clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

Your goal is to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) only the rows for which the background color in column F is `'#b7e1cd'` and copy these values to a different sheet.

- You don't need a loop to achieve this goal, you can directly filter the rows for which the background color in F is `'#b7e1cd'`.

  ```
  const new_values = values.filter((_,i)=>colors[i]=='#b7e1cd');
  ```

  where `values` is defined as the full [datarange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) of `Sheet1`:

  ```
  const values = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  ```

You can use `copyTo` in case you want to move data within the same spreadsheet file. This is why I prefer `getRange/setValues` because it does not have this limitation.

### Solution:

The following script will paste the values starting from the cell `A1` of `Sheet2`. If you want a different starting cell, modify `1,1` in `target_sh.getRange(1,1,..)` to a different cell reference.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // put the name of the source sheet
  const target_sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2'); // put the name of the target sheet
  const colors = sh.getRange('F1:F').getBackgrounds().flat();
  const values = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const new_values = values.filter((_,i)=>colors[i]=='#b7e1cd');
  target_sh.getRange(1,1,new_values.length,new_values[0].length).setValues(new_values);
}
```

**Updated code based on your sheet:**

```
function iftest() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('HH 2 - Main Database'); // put the name of the source sheet
  const target_sh = ss.getSheetByName('HH 1 - New Database'); // put the name of the target sheet
  const colors = sh.getRange('F1:F').getBackgrounds().flat();
  console.log(colors);
  const values = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let LastRow = target_sh.getLastRow();
  const new_values = values.filter((_, i) => colors[i]=='#ff6d01');
  target_sh.getRange(LastRow+1,1,new_values.length,new_values[0].length).setValues(new_values);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I have only one question, in the line 
```  const new_values = values.filter((_,i)=>colors[i]=='#b7e1cd'); ``` 
What is the meaning of (_, i) ? Because for some reason, the script returns an error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" and I suppose the problem is with the variable new_vales

Comment: @Filipa can you share a copy of your sheet ? I am afraid column F does not contain the desired color . Remove all the sensitive information.

Comment: is there any way that I can share it directly to you or you give me your email so that I add you to the sheet? It's just that this document isn't mine and I would prefer not sharing it publicly

Comment: @Filipa create a mock sheet example, where you have some fake data in it. Just to create a minimul reproducible example. And share that example here. You can then remove the link afterwards

Comment: @Filipa 1) create a target sheet with the name `HH 1 - New Database`. 2) your background color (for the names Mary etc..) wasn't `B7E1CD` but `#ff6d01`. 3) copy the updated code in my answer in a different script to make sure you are running only `iftest`.  The script will get the rows for which column F is orange (rows 10,12,13).

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your help and sorry for the bother! I made some stupid mistakes... Already accepted your answer, thank you once again :)

Comment: @Filipa no worries! you are welcome. Happy coding :)